# iMac (27 in, Late 2013, 32 GB 1600 MHz DOR3 memory running MacOS 10.15.7

Tags: imac

Great device but getting long of tooth.  Was notified recently that Stack will no longer run on it after October 2023.  What are my options for extending my late 2013 (maxed on memory chips)life?

Terry

Comment: What do you mean with „extending it‘s life“, what do you want to use it for? What kind of research have you done on this?

Comment: You can try running OpenCore Legacy Patcher to run a newerOS. That's pretty much it. Bear in mind that Apple will probably remove Intel support from the OS in 2 or 3 years, so you'll need to save up for a new Mac, if you want to stay in the game.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Very helpful!